# I can't get list employed who has ID over ID of condition i have input in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm having a problem about Core Data, can you help me to resolve it? I have a table contains all employees. Any employee has id in crease 1....
And now I want to fetch any employee record if this record has satisfied
condition.
Example: get records of employees who have id over 10.

```
NSPredicate *_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                           @"(id > %i)",
                           10];
```

But the result always return for me 0.
I have checked on local database, on this database all employee has stored in it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @hanh-bang : is id is Int or String?? Please post complete NSFetchRequest code

Comment: @SandeepBhandari
It's int.
The code's below.
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Staffs"]; 
NSPredicate *_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(id > %i)", lastID]; 
[request setPredicate:_predicate]; 
[request setFetchLimit:2]; 
NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
request = nil; 
return fetchedObjects;

Answer (score 0):

If your id is Int than use this

```
NSPredicate *_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                       @"(id > %d)",
                       10];
```

Comment: i have just changed to same with you
NSPredicate *_predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                       @"(id > %d)",
                       10];

but it don't woked. ;(

Comment: it always return 0 to me.